# Find the type of visible field from visible_fields()

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-forms

I've the following code inside my `forms.py`. I'm using ModelForm to generate the form view

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(NewPlayerForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for visible in self.visible_fields():
            print(visible)
            visible.field.widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
```

The aim is to not put the `form-control` class on a field of type boolen/checkbox. But I'm having a hard time in figuring out how to get the field type from the above lines.

`print(visible)` shows the following in the console

I tried using `field.type` or `field.getType()`, nothing seems to work.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check this by looking for the `.field.widget.input_type`:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(NewPlayerForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    for visible in self.visible_fields():
        if visible.field.widget.input_type == 'checkbox':
            visible.field.widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
```